# Reusing Views ios

Tags: ios, user-interface, ios5, reusability

Trying to develop a test app wherethe look is like ebook. user can flip the pages. However, app will have 40-50 pages to go through. Is there anyway to just update one view and even after re using you can easily turn it over and back. or do I have to create more views to achieve objective.
Can someone pls provide suggestion on which technique to use to solve this issue and also what to use for flipping like ebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have tagged your question with `iOS5` you can use a [UIPageViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html) (see also [this one](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH4-SW3)) to handle this behavior for you (datasource handling, gesture handling etc.). The logic behind it is that you provide an array of view controllers where each one controls and provides content for a page in your book.

Comment: For easier manipulation I found http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPageViewController_Application  Which is a bit different format but very good implementation for beginner

Answer (score 0):

One way is, please look in to "page base application". Please create a new project as page base application and work on that. You will find good amount of documentation online for this.